# How do I define a policy value for a Chrome extension using the managed storage API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-apps, google-apps-for-education

I have written a Chrome extension that uses the [managed storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/storage) to allow Google Apps administrators to configure its "options" via a policy name and value.  When I install the extension I see a new section at chrome://policy for the extension and an indication that there are "No policies set."

I'm trying to figure out how to set this from the Google Apps management console.  I have a Chrome management license and can install the extension, but I don't see any obvious place to define values for the extension's option as defined in its schema.json file.

I do see documentation at http://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-policy-for-extensions but I'm on a Chromebook and am assuming there is some way to specify this from admin.google.com for my domain.

Am I missing something obvious?  Thanks.

Comment: You probably should add Google Apps-related tags to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're still working on it :-) This is being tracked at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=361156 (sorry, only visible by project members for now) and we're targeting ChromeOS 37.

We're also interested in use cases you'd like to support via this API and the console. Please file bug reports or feature requests at crbug.com, using the Enterprise template.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I have submitted https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375284 to record my use case.

Comment: Is this available in the meantime? I still cannot find anything in the "Chrome Mangement" section of the admin console. Does it require a chrome management license?

Comment: There is still no way to test these configuration files locally?

Comment: I agree. A way to locally validate an app's settings schema JSON and the policy file that can be uploaded via the Chrome Management Console would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This is now available in chromebox management console for managed devices under: Device Management -> Chrome App Management -> App Name, then "Upload configuration file".